# Moving boxes animation is not working if I add menu Items

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have found an effect [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/18/little-boxes-menu-with-jquery/) and tried to implement the same adding some more menus like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wHSGj/) fiddle.  HTML and Javascript code are bit bigger that is why I am not posting the code. But only two menu Items are coming. Please help me on this.. I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing all the menu items on the same location "top:0px;left:0px;". Menu items are present, but hidden behind each other.